# To redirect os.system() output to a .txt file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I have list of Unix commmands `("uname -a","uptime","df -h","ifconfig -a","chkconfig --list","netstat -rn","cat /proc/meminfo","ls -l /dev")` and I want to run them and redirect the entire output to a `.txt` file. I searched a lot but didn't get a proper solution, or I understood things wrongly.

I'm able to get the output on stdout with this for loop but I can't redirect to a file.

```
def commandsoutput():
    command = ("uname -a","uptime","df -h","ifconfig -a","chkconfig --list","netstat -rn","cat /proc/meminfo","ls -l /dev")

    for i in command:
        print (os.system(i))

commandsoutput()
```

Comment: have a look at the `subprocess` module which allows you to redirect `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer uses `os.popen`, which allows you to write the output of the command in your file:

```
import os
def commandsoutput():
    commands = ("uname -a","uptime","df -h","ifconfig -a","chkconfig --list","netstat -rn","cat /proc/meminfo","ls -l /dev")
    with open('output.txt','a') as outfile:
        for command in commands:
            outfile.write(os.popen(command).read()+"\n")
commandsoutput()
```

Answer (score 3):

`os.system` returns the exit code of the command, not its output. It is also deprecated.

Use `subprocess` instead:

```
import subprocess

def commandsoutput():
     command = ("uname -a","uptime","df -h","ifconfig -a","chkconfig --list","netstat -rn","cat /proc/meminfo","ls -l /dev")

     with open('log.txt', 'a') as outfile:
         for i in command:
              subprocess.call(i, stdout=outfile)

commandsoutput()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, when i run this i'm getting these errors.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    commandsoutput()
  File "test2.py", line 8, in commandsoutput
    subprocess.call(i, stdout=outfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory